# Changing adjustable fixture light bulb when socket and housing are loose

Tags: light-fixture, bulb, light

I'm having trouble changing a ceiling mounted adjustable fixture lightbulb. So there's two issues: one, the metal housing is loose and when I try screwing it in, there's a lot of grinding and varying pressure and popping. I'm wondering if the bent section means it's broken? And two, even if I do get it reasonably tight, the light bulb socket rotates independently and won't allow me to loosen the bulb to change it.

Thanks all. I know this may be a simple question, but my level of home improvement skill is quite low; and with how high up and hard to see it is, I'm afraid of breaking something since I don't know what I'm doing.

Cheers!

[image]
[image]

Comment: My advise is replace the fixture.  You can also take that one apart and screw it back together, but a great replacement LED fixture can be had for very little money these days.

Comment: Nice photos!  They're worth thousands of words....

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the lampholder part of the fixture had a [threaded boss](http://thumbs2.picclick.com/d/l400/pict/282167248081_/Weld-on-threaded-boss-3-8-16-Aluminum.jpg), which the swivel post screwed into, and that has broken.

You might be able to repair by disassembling and using washers, lockwashers and a matching threaded nut on the inside of the lampholder part. It would take significant effort so it might be easier/better to just replace the fixture. You should definitely not use it like it is.